# No space left during update

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, android

I have got a Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Ubuntu 13.10, a write protected flash installation (Not even password change seems to be possible.) My free space is 12.7 GB. "Last update 2000-01-01" seems to show that all previous attempts to update where unsuccessful. When I try to update with button "Check for updates" it tells me "Ubuntu phone, Version 31". The download seems to complete 100%. Then error message, something like,

**Error 28: No more space left**.

`df -h` shows more or less plenty of space left, except for,

- /android/cache used 100% of 426M,
- /android/system used 98% of 59M,
- /tmp used 87% of 347M.

(Update of individual apps has worked previously. Now double entries of apps appear in "Storage => Installed apps, by name".)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently on Samsung Galaxy Nexus, Ubuntu updates are not possible since there is only 13GB of free space. This is apparently not sufficient for an update of Ubuntu.  My phone is basically identical to my October flash installation. I have meanwhile deleted the few files I have added (just some pictures) and uninstalled the few installed apps. I have 13GB of free space. When trying to update, the error message is still:
"Updates, Ubuntu Phone 301.1 MB, Version 32, Download failed: [Errno 28]No space left on device". On the positive side, copying the pictures to a linux PC with the Terminal app and

```
scp  ... ...
```

over WLAN did work nicely (faster than 1MB/sec). So pictures are not lost when you try to reflash the phone.